# Mozilla/1.0 Mozilla/2.0 Mozilla/3.0 Mozilla/4.0 Mozilla/5.0

Tags: code-golf, string, browser

> In the beginning there was NCSA Mosaic, and Mosaic called itself **`NCSA_Mosaic/2.0 (Windows 3.1)`**, and Mosaic displayed pictures along with text, and there was much rejoicing.

***15 years later...***

> And then Google built Chrome, and Chrome used Webkit, and it was like Safari, and wanted pages built for Safari, and so pretended to be Safari. And thus Chrome used WebKit, and pretended to be Safari, and WebKit pretended to be KHTML, and KHTML pretended to be Gecko, and all browsers pretended to be Mozilla, and Chrome called itself **`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.27 Safari/525.13`**, and the user agent string was a complete mess, and near useless, and everyone pretended to be everyone else, and confusion abounded.

[Read full story here...](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

Given a User Agent string, return the browser that it corresponds to.

You must support:

- Chrome/Chromium*
- Opera
- Firefox
- IE
- Edge
- Safari

Your code only needs satisfy all of these test cases.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
Edge

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
Edge

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
Chromium

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.32
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chromium

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.39
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Firefox
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the least bytes wins.

---

<sup>* Chromium and Chrome can be interchanged.</sup>

Comment: Why don't we need to detect any Mozilla 1-4, as the title suggests?

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
.+Tr.+
IE
.+E.+
Edge
.+P.+
Opera
.+?([CFS]\w+).+
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fTzukSE@by9OVS0/bFchwTUlPBTIDgEz/gtSiRCDbXiPa2S04NqZcWxMoqmL4/z8A) Explanation: Opera can be identified by its `(O)P(R/)` platform and IE by its `Tr(ident)` engine. The other browsers include their full name in their user agent, but Edge puts theirs last so it has to be processed separately from the others. Edit: Saved 1 byte by detecting Edge after Trident and 1 byte by detecting Opera using just the `P` both thanks to @ThePirateBay.

Comment: Thanks to we do not need to support UA like `Opera/10.0 ...`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
-7ịO%25ị“ðh³`Ẹ|Ḥ©®jḋƝ,Ṁ⁵»Ḳ¤
```

A monadic link accepting and returning lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/X/OHubn9VI1Mg9ahhzuENGYc2JzzctaPm4Y4lh1YeWpf1cEf3sbk6D3c2PGrcemj3wx2bDi35//@/b35VZk5Oor6pnoGCRnhmXkp@ebGCX4iCmZ6htQKQb2ZirVABIorKrExN9Aw0FdxTk7Pz9Y0MDA2AyFDBLbMoNS2/Qh8kCQA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##1VjLbtNAFN33K2YBUiu143l4xjGRkBAqULUhiAZaViFNXeLWtSMngYBYFDZd9BforhsQQgiolNJdKvEfzo8E2yEkaU0a22OTSFGisTPnnHvPnTtj72qG8brbXVKc86P8TcLcn87Bh4uvlfb3587P1lunddL@2P6y67SOfh0vOmcHnXen7XOn9a190vW@T52zT4urF4c3dt1pYOk26BwczznnPy4OO@8/P@t2c9Yb3TBKEoMIzG/o5rb1qgYeFgBGEGWBe4HLWdDk8gK4U60a2oa2tarXJUYVSDmYX31QyK0tAkPf08B9rbxnLYC7Fdva1ySmQgQpUjDEmIH10k7J1vvTen@ZG6HOlcq6WbdqlSxYMeuaAdwLIL8ONl0lRUyKLGkBQ7FzSKcndFzkSQvYxDgL1nSz0QTNDC8mH/FIrvH/Li2eYrixl1XGpyaqS40ExC7P0LLiLjNRiQwzSuzIUcoNBU@T6SxpAdEbypOthllv9ED1xv5w0pEa4IR7MYIT@Y1Ue1zcRc@RR40xgUpGgP10@veTkPV2KdfpW5tGQQncpTM87Kohs30gSq1/BXQoWcCSRbN0BIzWk9PqjgL3ppGqSmivJtPvPPbOZQqSXee5gIjxLB3H/8auXC765e0XmoTdpMhUpf4oORXEVyFTNwE8UAaDmCE@mQxvL8sC@@UtJntbqU8lEYSR@8Hgnm5rO1ZT8m72BxOctuIA@hXaW3yjlRoHdFwVQkwEJeCys8LyShMwKqlk4tjmizL9H2BkHBiZuM5Fu8z6pgjSN6iXaIDB2ZPZGDDvZpSSQaLrOnYKrzRHOg6RRjBFKGDB1rc1sy4psJdKjD30wd4BVpYnCzUOkC8oHgCNLqRs7VdLdX3L0LIgt76yDNQ/vXiAjgawzBsMjxaiAOJQgBPlvGA1ypWoHibyyJZ/9FiS/ZdxTFUgU0C@qtmlFKRceWwdVUJJakquSwpVg6SEfC/HEYUEyoGKnmp2TbdMyWuWEPe19Gf0hrHegntQFGauJyfD5N6M8OQ4iJxAFjpyFily@So5dm2@ln2Y258QnhwFe55O5Fi0578B) (shows `expected output -> output`; tests sorted by browser).

#### How?

```
-7ịO%25ị“ðh³`Ẹ|Ḥ©®jḋƝ,Ṁ⁵»Ḳ¤ - Link: list of character, userAgentString
-7ị                         - -7 index into userAgentString (last character is 0)
   O                        - cast to ordinal
    %25                     - modulo by 25
                          ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
        “ðh³`Ẹ|Ḥ©®jḋƝ,Ṁ⁵»   - compression of dictionary words:
                            -   = "IE Firefox Opera Safari Chrome Edge"
                         Ḳ  - split at spaces
       ị                    - index into (1-indexed and modular)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>113</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

Same approach as the [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137817/22867) by Neil.

```js
f=_=>_[x=`includes`]`P`?`Opera`:_[x]`Tr`?`IE`:_[x]`E`?`Edge`:_.match(/[CFS]\w+/)[0]
```

Previous attempts:

```js
// With String.prototype.test, 83 bytes
f=_=>/P/.test(_)?`Opera`:/Tr/.test(_)?`IE`:/E/.test(_)?`Edge`:_.match(/[CFS]\w+/)[0]

// With array filtering, 113 bytes
f=_=>_[o=`Opera`,i=`includes`]`P`?o:[o,`Edge`,`Firefox`,`Chromium`,`Chrome`,`Safari`].filter(b=>_[i](b))[0]||`IE`
```

### Try it:

```js
const f=_=>_[x=`includes`]`P`?`Opera`:_[x]`Tr`?`IE`:_[x]`E`?`Edge`:_.match(/[CFS]\w+/)[0]

const testData = {
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393': 'Edge',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063': 'Edge',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36': 'Chromium',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57': 'Opera',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.32': 'Opera',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8': 'Safari',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36': 'Chromium',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.39': 'Opera',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko': 'IE',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36': 'Chrome',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0': 'Firefox',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0': 'Firefox'
}

Object.keys(testData).forEach(ua => {
  console.log('Expected: %s; actual: %s (input: %s)', testData[ua], f(ua), ua)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 64 + 1 (-p) = 65 bytes

```perl
$_=/P/&&Opera||/Edge|Firefox/&&$&||/C/&&Chrome||/Tr/&&IE||Safari
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vhbb9owFH7vr/BDVRVpdXx8Cxnaw1R1W9UyqpWtfUMB3DVqSKIQOjbx28ccaFeugZALrcQDduTz@Zzj853PDlToinHf/l0bH7Y@GFfG0VEjUKE9Ghln3Z9q9MkJ1Z0/1NOHR3ruVP85vQ/9ntKDZqhH52ej0bV9Z4fOeFz3/ziuaxsCE3R843hd/1cffW0iIJjUkJ6QvIaGklfQxyBw1Y1qXziRIZiJmUTHF1@a9ct3yHUeFPqsOg9@BU2hDGFhghkxAQMINEV7WnYwh1m3O44X@f37Gjr3IuUiPYEa1@hWb6EFtCVeC7IkDFPMV0L/UGHf8T1DR03DPoM@rTjYEOPGTRzj8PG94JhUpiYNSoDoH6DnbMYf11qSGPIyxF5B1qElC0O@BR2qS8cbDNGwKlsF@jhB@t4eeNFgHjF7sgvb85oz1QydrvIiw4wPrN48QLz5F6Dtk4uB7uL@plqVZUQkMydWJ5jU0pgkCzPJZWZiuLqZmegsM@kVW3taRMr4m0iZPuiYmoRj05qHRHGvNYBj4MxihRGqjPEtynHVLMtlOnGZMx1mudJngUEQydKkmxTYx5einVdDzWRhrrnnyZ@Qi1YonsSWGu0u@15jhCYZoWmZSOyJyGEVkVMsUktMkZfEmaqVqZvOoDdbg8RaUZjESi0mypMumbrXorV0FZwjHUsS@w9AsVnNohnY3u5RfPmQgza88ZTPnvF4wdoQi2eyTkcLCfendIZWkxQXCUbij3nfS7YlpYXDWaIMK7T@UwqQvXPtkn9VWZbCWx9S1Lj6ZvCJ6BSWiYVZwiYW/V7YA6MJZUvf6GvFDrU6q23TdaM8nzwIz9IKyJt41klWNR2/F9iR03ZVDdWvz8@Q9VQIL4kiLxkS8WB2VEltDba3lnxzIPlf46H4twiZU3cvXIHlKLvn6CFjfy@nUzBrh5tw0x907jNeiGNaoa@YVv4/IAGRWagTStZp05pjSTXHUijqjYb@@kGkyaE/PqlrW0DGJ4H7Dw)

The header and the -l in the TIO link are just to make the output easier to read when feeding the entire list of User-Agents.  Without those, this meets the challenge, taking one string and returning the browser name.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>133</s> <s>130</s> 128 bytes

```kotlin
"Tr|IE_E|Edge_P|Opera_mi|Chromium_C|Chrome_A|Safari".split("_").map{it.split("|")}.firstOrNull{it[0] in this}?.get(1)?:"Firefox"
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
    "Tr|IE_E|Edge_P|Opera_mi|Chromium_C|Chrome_A|Safari"
        .split("_")
        .map { it.split("|") }
        .firstOrNull {
            it[0] in this
        }?.get(1) ?: "Firefox"
```

### Test

```kotlin
fun String.f(): String =
"Tr|IE_E|Edge_P|Opera_mi|Chromium_C|Chrome_A|Safari".split("_").map{it.split("|")}.firstOrNull{it[0] in this}?.get(1)?:"Firefox"

data class Test(val input: String, val output: String)

val tests = listOf(
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393",
                "Edge"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063",
                "Edge"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36",
                "Chromium"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57",
                "Opera"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.32",
                "Opera"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8",
                "Safari"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
                "Chromium"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.39",
                "Opera"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
                "IE"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36",
                "Chrome"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",
                "Firefox"
        ),
        Test(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",
                "Firefox"
        ))

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val answers = tests
        .map { (i, o) -> Triple(i, o, i.f()) }
    val t = answers
        .groupBy { it.second }
        .mapValues { it.value.groupBy { it.second == it.third }.mapValues { it.value.size } }
    for (f in t) {
        println(f)
    }
    println(answers.groupBy { it.second == it.third }.mapValues { it.value.size })
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##5Vptb+I4EP7OrxjxKZE4Y+cN0h676q2422q3y+rKbVc6naIUAlgNCUqcbncLv71n54XSktI3SpI24gNxMs7j8XiembHPfOZS76o2ijw4ZgH1xmgkyXvpf+hc1fvB/LBrdefd4dixvs57MyewrSmdf5gE/pRGU+tD8texDubH9sgOaB2FM5cyqW7VZTS1Z5eUZS3zurxAIxqErBd8iVyXP/oX/wfUAzah4eI9GjtMIvL7vfqfNHBG/kX9qja0mQ0D1w5D6Dshk85tlwvMIpahbIBo8iO20ibXaqKRcYEQOuBS/sWRVIP0ijta3mVX/cj/RV3XbuoIg3RCvaH/I4QvfSAY4X3gDYa2DxeGJsPBbOY6J87pJ8qautpCqgHSp4/9o88N/q0zB/5yBme+DIlmmrqJMFJxiyBCdEi0lIrVG+swEqn68oHceBTwI3tAPeaHk3049JjjAm+A3jF85+OwiGLprwq+gVWkIC0X/zcnCKnvNfn8cewZ8lQiD3pqwE+Fvm4yvRNhMsH5nq4hLCe4mgommP8IpEbeFA/z4GSLYAt4DETKBUd9LQuKWEa54X8nfOo/Uy+6gIu2YZVd2zHcf04jj0U3YZdlHZVbfXes+X5Ah47Hmi3hlrgeCRF6vEabh+Sw+yJLBhGluKm8j12Myszus4OSdgxcMTlwXDirG+usrqL2/ayurLI6l9gJqy91Xl471t6OHXNPhpQW1lDLvIkbRM7SJBoimmqqeaMQL5QhnDHEEExFQ+1WpVSvxKrXVG4zRq7udUR0bGxf95vNH5c9x1kznXLlCSXAcSN/KlXwQkqUz1WE/NcykOJUeAcUZRMUpRgK16sc0ZG8iE5B+qPrNPoLRHRPz4iTvBSy4ucqbWAzh0uw+cB54J1tN+WrWJZagpD6NqYds84W4zIDi7kkREGtduGZnVrtcrO27sYIR3evH1v1YkLgZRNTPQvbiiCyDWXmIuDkU7ymb4AiHu4ESrkp/ZYLqloJofy098i09XXETGuabhuVKnLcbSHQ+/p3U4uLN7rZQnorbyTxjnm5BnJ7Am6NQ1VedBwGUt7y3l9RHn210LTj0HabO5BYKzwkxG9nv/fB+evT4Q786cxm9NR19uHo+LALZurmrg0XX1usLm5W7+Qt2+oD4JAdwtlci8Rl3YAiFdnQM0qVN1Uj4d9i9ewGFz6DILdUPdtdqKiauwgVc8i+70eDSdGbKIJElddOosttaYKNwkMWUsVcPvHM6ibPrO68orUdOHItPnI9takn2cE43IODILB//p6cXn4nw2X8rjjDbHvhD06Q0ElOMy/7EEer4RIk2gA+bb+9E+ucz3B83wAqznHLsFh2w3gHaVfXXYwDP5r98ZN3I85oOwPfG6Yi2Re+2W7khMkL5+J/rkynI27YhAZcPl8spL8cWKS9j/wApFF87jsbqrhmfPDM9aSRHDcl72aNKfjnfV+uLa7+Bw)

### Edits

- -3 [jrtapsell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73772) - Swapped destructuring for array access
- -2 [jrtapsell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73772) - Replaced contains with in